# How to get temporal credentials after auth with AWS ALB/Cognito/OIDC IdProvider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I have setup ALB built-in authentication with an OIDC identity provider (SalesForce) connected via Cognito User pool, more or less following [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/built-in-authentication-in-alb/).

With this setup my web application (Java/Spring Boot-based) receives the headers `x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken`, `x-amzn-oidc-identity` and  `x-amzn-oidc-data` forwarded by the ALB.
I can parse and validate JWT tokens contained in these headers and, for instance, get users's e-mail from there.

Now my goal is to give this authenticated user access to certain AWS resources or services via AWS JavaScript SDK, directly from the client side. For instance, I'd like the user to be able to list objects on an S3 bucket or call certain lambda functions.

My understanding is that I somehow need to generate temporal credentials for this authenticated user. But I could not find specific documentation on how to do this. The closest hits were:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempFederationTokenJava.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html

But I could not connect the dots there. My expectation is that I probably should use the `x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken`, `x-amzn-oidc-identity` and  `x-amzn-oidc-data` headers somehow, but I failed to find any code that would do it.

**So my question is: how do I generate temporal credentials for the user which was authenticated with built-in ALB authentication via Cognito with OIDC Identity Provider?**

Comment: Have you experimented with the Cognito service provider frameworks? They expose AWS services directly through SDKs and include "The credentials provider communicates with Amazon Cognito, retrieving both the unique identifier for authenticated and unauthenticated users as well as temporary, limited privilege AWS credentials for the AWS Mobile SDK. The retrieved credentials are valid for one hour, and the provider refreshes them when they expire."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/accessing-aws-services.html#accessing-aws-services-1.javascript

Comment: @lasleyd This implies "once the Amazon Cognito credentials provider is initialized and refreshed". And I can't find how to use `x-amzn-oidc-` headers for this.

Comment: Cognito docs aren't intuitive in this context. Have you been through this section already (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html) and have you glanced at any of the provider examples: https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/auth/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.html?

Comment: @lasleyd Yes, I saw these docs. I can validate the JWT Token from `x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken` or `x-amzn-oidc-data`, but I still don't know how to create temporal credentials with these tokens.

Comment: Ok, since you're using Java/Spring, do you have a JWT processor defined as noted here? https://gorillalogic.com/blog/java-integration-with-amazon-cognito/ That would make accessing and manipulating the tokens much easier. The docs on Nimbus JOSE explain the parsing options/capabilities in more detail: https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt

Comment: @lasleyd We use a different method of token verification as explained here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html

Comment: @lasleyd Links you've send are interesting but somehow I can't match them with ALB authentication. For instance, they say "we extract the access token from the Authentication Header of the request" and but I don't have the `Authentication` header. The code overall does not seem suitable for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple steps that you need to take to achieve this.

First is to create an appropriate IAM role that you will let your users to assume. If you want to provide S3 access for your users then you need to tailor the IAM role in such way and set the trust relationship between that Role and `WebIdentity` (if you go to console -> IAM -> Roles -> Create Role, you will see this option on top of the screen - `Select type of trusted entity` and configure provider based on your actual OIDC provider).

Once you have that role, you will need to exchange the WebIdentity token that you currently posses for STS token. In your case, you will need to call `sts.assume_role_with_web_identity` function (which is part of SDK) where you will need to specify

- `RoleArn` - arn of the above created role, which will be assumed by your users
- `RoleSessionName` - name for the session user (can be arbitrary string)
- `WebIdentityToken` - OIDC compliant token (the one that you currently have)
- `Duration` - how long the returned credentials will be valid

After you make the call, you will receive response containing:

```
'Credentials': {
    'AccessKeyId': 'string',
    'SecretAccessKey': 'string',
    'SessionToken': 'string',
    'Expiration': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
},
...
```

The important parts are `AccessKeyId`, `SecretAccessKey` and `SessionToken`. These 
 temporary credentials can be used to directly call S3, Lambda or any other AWS service from your code but you will need to configure your the SDK that you are currently using to include them. Once all that is done, you should be good to go without any issues.

Comment: You say "`WebIdentityToken` - OIDC compliant token (the one that you currently have)" - which one is it? Is it what the `x-amzn-oidc-identity` header contains?

Comment: I am not sure which one of those headers stores the actual token, it is either `x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken` or `x-amzn-oidc-data `.

Comment: I get *"The ID Token provided is not a valid JWT. (You may see this error if you sent an Access Token)"* if I send `X-Amzn-Oidc-Data`.  
I get *"Missing a required claim: aud"* if I send `X-Amzn-Oidc-Accesstoken`.  `x-amzn-oidc-identity` also did not work (not a valid JWT).

Comment: Seems like ALB is modifying the token somehow. I will look into how to reconstruct the token from the data received from ALB.

Comment: Example of `X_AMZN_OIDC_DATA` I'm trying to use:
https://pastebin.com/HXeL01w2
Is happily decoded by https://jwt.io.

Comment: If I'm not using OIDC but using Cognito for authentication rule on the load balancer, should I be able to see header x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken? Currently I only see aws cookies